# While extruding my whole mesh vertices doesn't remain connected creating a separate prt

Tags: modeling, mesh, extrude

In vertex mode i am selecting whole object by pressing A ,and hitting E to extrude in y direction ...I want extrusion to remain connected at vertices but its not remaining connected [here is the blend file](https://www.dropbox.com/s/7ne68pctk7nfjiw/car.blend?dl=0)?

Comment: It looks as if you have already extruded your object but left the extrusion in place. In edit mode with everything selected press M > Merge by distance and you'll see that the number of vertices in the status bar halves from 68 to 34. Then E > Y again and it works as expected.

Comment: Please don't link to a file in Dropbox, to make it available in the future it's best to upload it here: [Blend-Exchange.com](https://blend-exchange.com/) Follow the instructions there.

Comment: Hello and welcome. Please provide some context and explanation by verbally describing your issue, don't just post, images, videos, files to download, or links to external sites. See [What is the problem with posting an image or link and asking “*How do I do this?*”](https://blender.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2449)

Answer (score 1):

As John wrote correctly, you have already done an extrusion and now you have doubled your vertices in place.

So what you can do is just box select your whole object (by this you just select the upper vertices), then press <kbd>X</kbd> -> Vertices. Which deletes the upper vertices.

Then press <kbd>A</kbd> to select All and extrude as you want.